# How to view logs (Console.log) after ejecting from expo?

Tags: javascript, xcode, react-native, terminal, expo

In my react native app am using expo.In order to implement InAppPurchase feature using expo-in-app-purchases,am ejecting my app using expo eject.Then i running it on my device(ios 14.2).But I am no longer able to see log outputs.where should i see the logs.After ejecting i build the solution with xcode.What i have is:

App.js

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    console.log("componentDidMount");//this logs
    try {
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
    } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
    }
    connectSocket(store);
    const history = await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
    console.log("history", history);//this logs where should i see those logs?
   }
```

If anyone can provide any help or advice would be really appreciated.